# Is my below code thread safe while removing elments from LinkedBlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a below method which is called by multiple threads concurrently to get the live socket. It takes `LinkedBlockingQueue` as the parameter and then I iterate and see if there is any liveSocket available and if it is available then I remove and return that socket.

```
  private Optional<Holder> getSocket(final LinkedBlockingQueue<Holder> endPoints) {
    Optional<Holder> liveSocket = Optional.absent();
    if (!endPoints.isEmpty()) {
      for (Holder state : endPoints) {
        // check if socket is live? if yes then remove and return that.
        if (state.isLive()) {
          liveSocket = Optional.of(state);
          endPoints.remove(state);
          return liveSocket;
        }
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }
```

Wanted to check if my above code is thread safe or not? Here `Holder` is an immutable class.

Comment: The queue operations are thread-safe, but the state of the contained objects is not.  What happens if the `liveSocket` is made non-live by another thread between when you check its state and when you remove it from the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue manipulation operations are thread safe, so the `remove()` will not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.  However, you have thread-safety problems around the state of the objects contained in the queue.

There's a race condition between when you check the "live" state of the `Holder` object and when you remove it from the queue.  Another thread could be running in the same code at the same time, with the likely result that both threads would take the same object.  Whichever thread got to the `remove()` call last would get a `false` return, but you don't examine the result so you'd never know.  Both threads would then attempt to use the same object.

You need to synchronize around the search/remove operation.

For curiosity, here's the code I used to show that `ConcurrentModificationException` does not occur with `LinkedBlockingQueue`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String[] data = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g" };
    LinkedBlockingQueue<String> lb = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(Arrays.asList(data));

    new Thread(() -> 
    { 
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            lb.add("x");
            System.out.println("added");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            lb.remove("e");
            System.out.println("removed");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }).start();

    for (String s : lb)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

If you substitute `LinkedList` for `LinkedBlockingQueue` you get the `ConcurrentModificationException` as expected.

Output:

```
a
b
added
c
removed
d
f
g
x
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not only not thread-safe, it's wrong even within a single thread. You will get a `ConcurrentModificationException` on the `remove()`. You need to use an explicit `Iterator` and to do the removal via the `Iterator`.

And for correctness via multiple threads you need synchronization or a semaphore around the loop.

NB The `isEmpty()` test is pointless. The iteration already has to check for that. Don't keep a dog and bark yourself.

Comment: Actually, the remove works just fine and there is no CME with the `LinkedBlockingQueue` (in contrast with a plain `LinkedList`).  I was curious so I tried it, the `java.util.concurrent` collections are thread-safe as described in the Javadoc. However, there are thread safety issues around the objects contained in the queue.